# Adding Controller Macros in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec2

Im trying to define some controller macros for Rspec. Im using rails 3 and have my macros defined in spec/support/macros/controller_macros.rb, that file looks like this:

```
module ControllerMacros
    def self.login_admin
        #code
    end
end
```

in my spec helper I have:

```
config.include(ControllerMacros, :type => :controller)
```

So in my controller spec i just call login_admin in my admin tests but when ever i use the method i get

```
undefined local variable or method `login_admin' for #<Class:0xb6de4854> (NameError)
```

At first I assumed that controller_macros.rb wasn't being included but when I added a "puts" to the file but that showed the file was at least being executed.

I can't see anything wrong with my setup and copying the login_admin method into the describe block works fine so im not sure whats wrong with it.

Comment: I'm not an expert on this but I think it's to do with the scoping ( self. ) of the method as its defined at class level. You may have to include it or extend it with base.included  or base.extended, or maybe remove the self.

Comment: sorry self.included or self.extended

Answer (score 10):

Maybe I am  late to that, but for new comers.

Here is a good examples of using macros:

http://osmose.6spot.com.br/2011/01/rails-resource-routing-spec-w-rspec/

when you **include** a module it's methods are visible inside examples.

But when you **extend** the module, it's methods are only visible outside examples.

It gives you ways to compose your macros for each situation.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
ControllerMacros.login_admin
```

or remove `self` from the method definition.

Comment: That does work but isnt the way it should really be done with rspec

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment. If you're defining a macro, you want to include it in many different examples, no? So there's no need to define a class method using `self`. Or did you mean something else?

Answer (score 1):

**One line answer:** Remove self from the method definition

**Why?** The methods of included modules are available in RSpec examples

The `login_admin` method defined in `ControllerMacros` will be available in your RSpec example as `login_admin`

**To Be Specific:**

Rewrite `spec/support/macros/controller_macros.rb` as

```
module ControllerMacros
    def login_admin
        #code
    end
end
```

Then tell Rspec to include the Macros

`config.include(ControllerMacros, :type => :controller)`