# Trouble including controller macros for rspec tests /w devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, devise, macros

I am getting a uninitialized constant ControllerMacros (NameError), perhaps similar to these issues ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4229756/adding-controller-macros-in-rspec), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28837717/ruby-on-rails-abstractcontrollerhelpersmissinghelpererror-missing-helper-fi), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28360511/rspec-not-loading-controllermacros-module-in-linux-but-fine-on-os-x)). I must be screwing up the syntax while trying to include controller macros so I can login with devise and pass controller tests in rspec. [Link to GitHub repo](https://github.com/dadiletta/CareerFoundry_Ruby).
*Rails 4.1.8 and Ruby 2.1.2*

**spec/controllers/static_pages_controller_spec.rb**

```
require 'rails_helper'


describe StaticPagesController, :type => :controller do
  describe "GET #index" do
    it "responds successfully with an HTTP 200 status code" do
      login_user
      get :index
      expect(response).to be_success
      expect(response).to have_http_status(200)
    end

    it "renders the index template" do
      login_user
      get :root
      expect(response).to render_template("index")
    end
  end

end
```

**spec/support/controller_macros.rb**

```
module ControllerMacros
  def login_admin
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:admin]
      admin = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
      sign_in :user, admin # sign_in(scope, resource)
    end
  end

  def login_user
    before(:each) do
      @request.env["devise.mapping"] = Devise.mappings[:user]
      user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
      user.confirm! # or set a confirmed_at inside the factory. Only necessary if you are using the "confirmable" module
      sign_in user
    end
  end
end
```

added lines to **spec/rails_helper**

```
   #helps avoid authentication error during rspec:
    config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
    config.include ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looks like you may need to add `require 'support/controller_macros'` to the top of your `rails_helper.rb` file. This directory would not be included by default with RSpec.

Comment: I can't believe it was that easy.

Comment: For me adding `config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller` worked

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me.

spec/support/devise.rb

```
require 'devise'

RSpec.configure do |config|
 config.include Devise::TestHelpers, :type => :controller
 config.extend ControllerMacros, :type => :controller
end
```

Also make sure this line is uncommented in rails_helper.rb

```
Dir[Rails.root.join('spec/support/**/*.rb')].each { |f| require f }
```